# Find substrings within between 2 string fragments

Tags: postgresql, view, pattern-matching, postgresql-9.0

I am trying to populate a view in PostGIS in Postgres 9.0 and in this view I want it to contain a substring based on 2 string positions. See below for my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_actions AS 
 SELECT ls.f_table_schema, ls.f_table_name, 
 (SELECT substr(ls.attribute_actions_text, 
 strpos(ls.attribute_actions_text, 'name="')+6, 
 strpos(ls.attribute_actions_text, '"/>') - 
 strpos(ls.attribute_actions_text, 'name="'))) AS actions
   FROM layer_styles ls;
```

The outcome is that it doesn't like minus numbers when using strpos. I can get it go forward 6 characters to remove the 'name="' from the returned substring but cannot remove the '"/>'.

It returns the following:

```
View SHED Database"/>
```

where I want it return:

```
View SHED Database
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**ADDITION**:I have found out that if I was using 9.1 I could have used strposrev and i think the following code would have worked:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_actions AS 
 SELECT ls.f_table_schema, ls.f_table_name, 
 (SELECT substr(ls.attribute_actions_text::text, 
 strpos(ls.attribute_actions_text::text, 'name="'::text)+6, 
 strposrev(ls.attribute_actions_text::text, '"/>'::text)+3 - 
 strpos(ls.attribute_actions_text::text, 'name="'::text))) AS actions
   FROM layer_styles ls;
```

Comment: Try `replace(ls.f_table_schema,'"/>','')`?

Comment: I would have expected the definition of the underlying table (`\d tbl` in psql) and some sample values for this question.

Comment: I will do so in further questions, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**substring()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) with a regular expression instead:

```
substring(ls.attribute_actions_text FROM 'name="(.*?)"/>')
```

The dot (`.`) matches *any* character, `*?` is the non-greedy [quantifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE) for a sequence of 0 or more matches and the parentheses (`()`) mark the substring to be returned.

Like your code, this selects the first string matching the pattern and does not look further.

Also, you don't need to make your expression a subquery, that adds nothing but overhead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_actions AS 
SELECT ls.f_table_schema
     , ls.f_table_name
     , substring(ls.attribute_actions_text FROM 'name="(.*?)"/>') AS actions
FROM   layer_styles ls;
```

Quick test case (you should have provided):

```
SELECT *, substring(ls.attribute_actions_text FROM 'name="(.*?)"/>')
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('bar name="View SHED Database"/> foo')
   , ('bar name="View SHED Database"/> fooname="View SHED Database"/>xx')
   , ('name="buntch a bull"/> fooname="View SHED Database"/>xx')
   , ('xxname="bla foo grr"/>')
   , ('')
   , (NULL)
   ) ls(attribute_actions_text)
```

Comment: Erwin, thanks for this. I knew I should of added a test case showing my inputs and will do so in future. What does the (.*?) do?  

It works perfectly though, thankyou very much.

Comment: @danielfranklin: I added explanation & link above.